# Next/Previous buttons on virtual keyboard making text input field scroll into view on iOS uiWebview

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have a UI webview in iOS displaying a html page with two text input fields.  When clicking on one text input field and using the Next button on the virtual keyboard, the second text input field receives focus but does not scroll into view.  How can I make it scroll into view?